# Python logging: log only to handlers not to root

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class:

```
class Log(object):

# class new
#new is used instead of init because __new__ is able to return (where __init__ can't)
def __new__(self, name, consolelevel, filelevel):

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(message)s')

    #Create consolehandler and set formatting (level is set in the ROOT)
    consolehandler = StreamHandler()
    consolehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    #Create filehandler, set level and set formatting
    filehandler = FileHandler(name + '.log')
    filehandler.setLevel(filelevel)
    filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    #Create the root logger, add console and file logger. Set the rootlevel == consolelevel.
    self.root = logging.getLogger(name)

    #causing me problems....
    self.root.setLevel(consolelevel)

    self.root.addHandler(consolehandler)
    self.root.addHandler(filehandler)
    self.root.propagate = True

    return self.root

# Close the logger object
def close():
    # to be implemented
    pass
```

I use this class to log to the console and to a file (depending on the set level). The problem is that the root level seems to be leading for the addhandlers. Is there a way to disable this? Now I set the rootlevel to the same level as the consolelevel but this does not work...

Any advice?

Thanks in advance and with best regards,

JR

Comment: "The problem is that the root level seems to be leading for the addhandlers." This has *no* meaning. Do you mean that the logger adds more handlers then what you thought?

Answer (score 1):

A problem that I can see in your code is that it will add more handlers whenever you instantiate the `Log` class. You probably do not want this.

Keep in mind that `getLogger` returns always the same instance when called with the same argument, and basically it implements the singleton pattern.
Hence when you later call `addHandler` it will add a new handler everytime.

*The* way to deal with `logging` is to create a logger at the module level and use it.

Also I'd avoid using `__new__`. In your case you can use a simple function. And note that your `Log.close` method **wont** work, because your `__new__` method does not return a `Log` instance, and thus the returned logger doesn't have that method.

Regarding the level of the logger, I don't understand why you do not set the level on the `consolehandler` but on the whole logger.

Comment: ok, so probably I am using the wrong approach. I have a module with a few classes. I want to be able to have a separate log module for each class. I want to be able to set the console and file level independent for each class. What is the best approach to used?

Comment: I'll post some code later (because I don't have enough reputation...) to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of the module I am making. The module contains a few classes that all need a logging functionality. Each class logs to a different file and and it should also be possible to change the file handler levels between classes (e.g. gamepad class: console.debug and filehandler.info and MQTT class: console info and filehandler.debug).

Therefor I thought that setting up a log class would be the easiest way. Please bear in mind that I usually do electronics but now combined with python. So my skills are pretty basic....

```
#!/bin/env python2.7
```

from **future** import division
from operator import *
import logging
from logging import FileHandler
from logging import StreamHandler
import pygame
import threading
from pygame.locals import *
import mosquitto
import time
from time import sleep
import sys

class ConsoleFileLogger(object):

```
# class constructor
def __init__(self, filename, loggername, rootlevel, consolelevel, filelevel):

    # logger levels: DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL

    # define a root logger and set its ROOT logging level
    logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
    logger.setLevel(rootlevel)

    # define a Handler which writes messages or higher to the sys.stderr (Console)
    self.console = logging.StreamHandler()
    # set the logging level
    self.console.setLevel(consolelevel)

    # define a Handler which writes messages to a logfile
    self.logfile = logging.FileHandler(filename + '.log')
    # set the logging level
    self.logfile.setLevel(filelevel)

    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(message)s')
    self.console.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logfile.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add the handlers to the root logger
    logger.addHandler(self.console)
    logger.addHandler(self.logfile)

    self._logger = logger

# set a net instance of the logger
def set(self):
    return self._logger

# Stop and remove the ConsoleFileLogger object
def remove(self):
    self._logger.removeHandler(self.console)
    self._logger.removeHandler(self.logfile)
    self._logfile.FileHandler().close()
```

class Gamepad():

```
# class constructor
def __init__(self, mqttgamepad):
    self.logger = ConsoleFileLogger('BaseLogFiles/Gamepad', 'Gamepad', logging.INFO, logging.INFO, logging.INFO).set()

    if joystickcount == 0:
        self.logger.error('No gamepad connected')
    elif joystickcount == 1:
        self.gamepad = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        self.gamepad.init()
        self.logger.debug('Joystick name %s', self.gamepad.get_name())
        self.logger.debug('nb of axes = %s', self.gamepad.get_numaxes())
        self.logger.debug('nb of balls = %s', self.gamepad.get_numballs())
        self.logger.debug('nb of buttons = %s', self.gamepad.get_numbuttons())
        self.logger.debug('nb of mini joysticks = %s', self.gamepad.get_numhats())
    elif joystickcount > 1:
        self.logger.error('only one gamepad is allowed')

def run(self):
    self.logger.debug('gamepad running')
```

class MQTTClient():

```
def __init__(self, clientname):
    self.logger = ConsoleFileLogger('BaseLogFiles/MQTT/Pub', clientname, logging.DEBUG, logging.DEBUG, logging.DEBUG).set()
    self.logger.debug('test')

def run(self):
       self.logger.info('Connection MQTT Sub OK')
```

def main():
    logger = ConsoleFileLogger('BaseLogFiles/logControlCenterMain', 'ControlCenterMain', logging.DEBUG, logging.DEBUG, logging.DEBUG).set()

```
mqttclient = MQTTClient("MQTTClient")
mqttclient.connect()

gamepad = Gamepad(mqttclient)

if gamepad.initialized():
    gamepadthread = threading.Thread(target=gamepad.run)
    gamepadthread.start()

    mqtttpubhread = threading.Thread(target=mqttclient.run)
    mqtttpubhread.start()

logger.info('BaseMain started')

# Monitor the running program for a KeyboardInterrupt exception
# If this is the case all threads and other methods can be closed the correct way :)
while 1:
    try:
        sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.info('Ctrl-C pressed')
        gamepad.stop()
        mqttclient.stop()
        logger.info('BaseMain stopped')
        sys.exit(0)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

Comment: Anyone with some ideas? I really don't know how to continue. Thanks